# python2.5 multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have python2.5 and multiprocessoring (get from http://code.google.com/p/python-multiprocessing/)

This simple code (get from docs), works very strange from time to time, sometimes it ok, but sometimes it throw timeout ex or hang my Windows (Vista), only reset helps :) Why this can happen?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    print "fc",x
    return x*x
pool = Pool(processes=4)  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = pool.apply_async(f, (10,))     # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    print result.get(timeout=3)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a wild guess, but have you tried to move the `Pool` creation into the `if` block? I suspect that otherwise it might spawn an unlimited number of new processes, causing the freeze.

Comment: i was afraid to start this again :) but it works! thanx) really pull was creating over and over and this hangs.

Comment: @nikow: Why would processes be spawned indefinitely?  I can see the 4 initial children each creating a new pool of 4 children upon importing the program, but I don't see how they would run the main code and call `f` for each of their children…

Comment: @EOL: I suspect that in every child the module code is executed. Every time a new Pool is created, spawning 4 new children. I had this happen on my machine, and saw a very large number of Python processes before the machine froze.

Comment: @nikow: yes, but why would the 4 new children (for each new pool) create a "very large number of processes"?  I would expect the 4 normal children, plus 4*4 new processes, not more.  I don't see this as a reason to freeze…  I'm still puzzled. :)

Comment: @EOL: It's recursive. Each child accidentally creates a new pool with 4 new children. Note that the process in the first original children is no different from the one in their children. That's how `multiprocessing` is implemented.

Comment: @nikow: I see.  This is a Windows "detail", as only 1 `Pool` is created with Python 2.7 on OS X…

Comment: @EOL: Yes, I think the reason is that Windows does not support forking processes.